# Generating Android Achetype with akquinet / android-archetypes

Tags: android, maven

I am trying to generate an android archetype for a apklib so I can use [this library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). As [this pages](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkLib) shows I try to create it like this.

```
mvn archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=android-library-quickstart \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=com.slidingmenu \
  -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.9 \
  -DgroupId=com.sliding \
  -DartifactId=slidingmenu
```

However I get an error everytime. I get the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (com.slidingmenu:android-library-quickstart:1.0.9) -> [Help 1]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the wrong archetypeGroupId. Use this instead:

```
-DarchetypeGroupId=de.akquinet.android.archetypes
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this command as ben75 say

```
mvn archetype:generate \
  -DarchetypeArtifactId=android-library-quickstart \
  -DarchetypeGroupId=de.akquinet.android.archetypes \
  -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.9 \
  -DgroupId=com.sliding \
  -DartifactId=slidingmenu
```

and then add the library in your build path or in the pom file (with apklib as type)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to do mvn archetype:generate and generate a project in interactive mode. The archetype number for an android application is 95 ( search for android-quickstart ). See also question/answer: [maven archetype for an android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609753/maven-archetype-for-an-android-project)